# A messenger for my home network

Tags: networking

With the use of my router (ASUS) I have set up a home network. Is there software that I can use it to chat to other computers on my network? Which one is the best of them? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the one a lot of people swear by, AChat:

http://download.cnet.com/AChat/3000-2150_4-10633935.html

Answer (score 2):

Also try out [IP Messenger](http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en). Light weight and very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Pidgin supports chat using zeroconf (AKA bonjour) - you can install bonjour on your windows systems (or avahi on your linux systems), and use pidgin to chat - i believe macs support this natively with ichat.

Answer (score 1):

We used [VCM (Virtual Corporate Messenger)](http://www.http-tunnel.com/html/solutions/messenger.asp) at university.  We also used the main product at the site to get passed the port-blocking in order to use Napster and CuteMX, heehee.